# How to get sum of nested tuples in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have the list `[(270,), (270,)]` and I want to add the values in the tuples together. How would I do this?

Note: The number of tuples will vary so I need a dynamic solution to add the values together

Comment: Do you want something like: `[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)]` -> `(a1+a2, b1+b2, c1+c2)`? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: The question needs some more clarity, like Chris asked, are you looking for the sum of elements across tuples by index, or sum of the tuples themselves? `[(a1, b1, c1), (a2, b2, c2)]` => `[a1+b1+c1, a2+b2+c2 ...]`

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla I want to do 270 + 270

Comment: @PRA7H1K your example of input and output does not clarify the issue. If the tuples can be of length longer than a single element, show us an example of longer tuples and the expected result.

Comment: And if they're always length 1, then say so (and tell us why you have such odd data, maybe it can be avoided and allow a better solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of tuples (varying in size), you can use the `sum` function in Python directly:

Initialize a variable to store the total sum
`total_sum = 0`

```py
# Initialize a variable to store the total sum
total_sum = 0

# Iterate through the list and add the values in each tuple to the total sum
for each_tup in tuple_list:
   total_sum += sum(each_tup)

print(total_sum)
```

Comment: It is unknown if this is the aim, due to lack of clarity, plus this can be written in one line: `total_sum = sum(y for x in tuple_list for y in x)`

Comment: That worked! Sorry for the lack of clarity but that is what I wanted. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chris Or `sum(map(sum, tuple_list))`.